# How to safely output query parameters in Rails in which the ampersand is not escaped

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xss, erb

Consider the following query parameters

```rb
{
  :param1=>"<script>alert('hi')</script>", 
  :param2=>"<script>alert('hi2')</script>"
}
```

I want to safely render these as query parameters in a link. The problem is demonstrated as follows:

```rb
[83] pry(main)> params
=> {:param1=>"<script>alert('hi')</script>", :param2=>"<script>alert('hi2')</script>"}
[84] pry(main)> params.to_query
=> "param1=%3Cscript%3Ealert%28%27hi%27%29%3C%2Fscript%3E&param2=%3Cscript%3Ealert%28%27hi2%27%29%3C%2Fscript%3E"
[85] pry(main)> ERB::Util.html_escape params.to_query
=> "param1=%3Cscript%3Ealert%28%27hi%27%29%3C%2Fscript%3E&amp;param2=%3Cscript%3Ealert%28%27hi2%27%29%3C%2Fscript%3E"
```

When `params.to_query` is rendered via ERB, the ampersand is escaped as well. You can probably pass these to url_for and link_to as query parameters, but for the purposes of this question, let's assume that's not possible.

In my case, I simply want to have the query parameters themselves safely escaped, but not have the ampersand escaped.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a potential solution, but I am curious about feedback from the community:

```rb
  def escape_query_params(url)
    # in my case, we have a string that can be parsed as a URI.
    uri = URI.parse(url)

    # then we split the query part across the "&".
    # and return an array that uses the technique in the below article
    # to concat strings starting with a SafeBuffer
    # and then use ActionView's `safe_join` to bring back the & 
    safe_query_params = safe_join(uri.query.split("&").map{|s| "".html_safe + s}, "&".html_safe)
    "".html_safe + uri.path + "?" + safe_query_params
  end
```

The above uses a technique from the following article on how to be safe with html_safe: https://product.reverb.com/stay-safe-while-using-html-safe-in-rails-9e368836fac1